# How to create multiple circular progress bar using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I followed a tutorial on how to create a circular progress bar but when copying the div into multiple progress bars with different values, the script only works for the first value. How would I be able to change the script in order to have multiple progress bars work with different values?

I think because document.querySelectorAll is creating a node list but not sure what the best way would be to loop through each item to work for multiple progress circles.

```js
let circularProgress = document.querySelectorAll(".circular-progress"),
  progressValue = document.querySelectorAll(".progress-value");

let progressStartValue = 0,
  progressEndValue = progressValue.innerText,
  speed = 10;

let progress = setInterval(() => {
  progressStartValue++;

  progressValue.textContent = `${progressStartValue}%`
  circularProgress.style.background = `conic-gradient(#7d2ae8 ${progressStartValue * 3.6}deg, #ededed 0deg)`;

  if (progressStartValue == progressEndValue) {
    clearInterval(progress);
  }
}, speed);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #7d2ae8;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 420px;
  padding: 50px 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #fff;
  row-gap: 30px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.circular-progress {
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: conic-gradient(#7d2ae8 3.6deg, #ededed 0deg);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.circular-progress::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 210px;
  width: 210px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.progress-value {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #7d2ae8;
}

.text {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #606060;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circular-progress">
    <span class="progress-value">50</span>
  </div>
  <span class="text">HTML & CSS</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="circular-progress">
    <span class="progress-value">67</span>
  </div>
  <span class="text">HTML & CSS</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="circular-progress">
    <span class="progress-value">80</span>
  </div>
  <span class="text">HTML & CSS</span>
</div>
```

Comment: querySelector grabs the first matching element only.

Comment: I changed it from querySelector to querySelectorAll.. what would be the best case to loop over the NodeList in this case? I am probably doing the loop incorrectly but i am getting errors and the counter doesn't end.

Comment: [.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) has a loop example. Those docs also tell you that it returns a NodeList. The docs for [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) also include details on how to iterate over it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is selecting the element properly.

**Answer**

Get the containers separately and access the elements `querySelector` inside a container.
Then get the progress value using `progressValue.textContent`.

This will select each progress bar and each progress bar value separately.

```js
let containers = document.getElementsByClassName("container");

for (var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
  let container = containers[i];

  let circularProgress = container.querySelector(".circular-progress"),
    progressValue = container.querySelector(".progress-value");

  let progressStartValue = 0,
    progressEndValue = progressValue.textContent,
    speed = 10;

  let progress = setInterval(() => {
    progressStartValue++;

    progressValue.textContent = `${progressStartValue}%`;
    circularProgress.style.background = `conic-gradient(#7d2ae8 ${progressStartValue * 3.6}deg, #ededed 0deg)`;

    if (progressStartValue == progressEndValue) {
      clearInterval(progress);
    }
  }, speed);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #7d2ae8;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 420px;
  padding: 50px 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #fff;
  row-gap: 30px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.circular-progress {
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: conic-gradient(#7d2ae8 3.6deg, #ededed 0deg);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.circular-progress::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 210px;
  width: 210px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.progress-value {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #7d2ae8;
}

.text {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #606060;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circular-progress">
    <span class="progress-value">50</span>
  </div>
  <span class="text">HTML & CSS</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="circular-progress">
    <span class="progress-value">67</span>
  </div>
  <span class="text">HTML & CSS</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="circular-progress">
    <span class="progress-value">80</span>
  </div>
  <span class="text">HTML & CSS</span>
</div>
```